# How to set SEO-Friendly onclick events for javascript created elements without event listeners?

Tags: javascript, seo

I'm implementing a framework-less SPA in pure JS.

[Google Search Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwGY-9lwTF4&list=PLKoqnv2vTMUPOalM1zuWDP9OQl851WMM9&index=3) youtube channel recommends **strictly avoiding javascript event handlers**. Instead, one should use the `onclick` property and History-API approach:

[image]

However, I'm creating my element entirely through javascript:

```js
const setViewState = function(entry, parentRoot){
    const element = document.createElement("a")
    element.href = entry.href
    element.innerHTML = `${entry.id} - ${entry.content}`
    element.id = `entry${entry.id}`
    
    parentRoot.appendChild(element)
}
```

How do I setup an onclick function on that javascript-created element without relying on event listeners?

I tried using `element.onclick = function` approach but it does not seem to generate an element with onclick prop. It seems to attach a click event listener:

[image]

Compare it to an element hardcoded to the HTML with the onclick the video refers:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking martin split himself on twitter, I'm convinced there's no issues on attaching event listeners as onlick to links for rendering content.

However, you **need** to indicate your route through href. And that rounting cannot be done through event listeners.

This is his original answer:

> The point of the sample code was just to explain that there must be an
> href with a resolvable URL. Googlebot doesn't care about event
> handlers and doesn't care about event listeners either, so use either
> at your own discretion :)